# Compare variables containing REG_MULTI_SZ registry value

Tags: powershell, variables, compare, registry

I need a script that periodically reads a registry value (REG_MULTI_SZ). If the value changed → do something.

```
$itemList1 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path Registry::HKCU\SOFTWARE\Tester -Name TestValue

# ...

$itemList2 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path Registry::HKCU\SOFTWARE\Tester -Name TestValue

if ($itemList1 -eq $itemList2) {echo "identical"} else {echo "different"}
```

- if the TestValue reg value is **empty**, the script outputs "**different**"
- if the TestValue reg value has **1 string only**, the script outputs
  "**identical**"
- if the TestValue reg value has **more than 1 string**, the
  script outputs "**identical**"

[image]

Can you suggest?

Comment: `Compare-Object $itemList1 $itemList2`

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, it looks working fine.

Comment: Can you indicate how can I obtain a $true value if the variables are equal and a $false value in case they are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REG_MULTI_SZ` values are basically string arrays. To compare arrays use [`Compare-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/Compare-Object).

```
Compare-Object $itemList1 $itemList2
```

To get a boolean value from the result just cast it to bool and invert the value:

```
![bool](Compare-Object $itemList1 $itemList2)
```

`Compare-Object` returns an empty result if the two compared objects are equal (and `-IncludeEqual` was not used), and PowerShell can [auto-convert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) empty/`$null` values to `$false`. Negating the value with `-not` or `!` inverts the logic from "`$false` if empty" to "`$true` if empty".

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice explanation, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PS C:>$a=1;$b=2;$c=1
 PS C:> if (Compare-Object $a $b) { Write-Host Different } else { Write-Host Equal }
 Different

 PS C:\Users\amewald> if (Compare-Object $a $c) { Write-Host Different } else { Write-Host Equal }
 Equal
```

[Msdn Compare-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Compare-Object):

> OUTPUTS
>
> None, or the objects that are different

That means `Compare-Object` returns `$null` if both objects are the same.

Hope that helps